# How to use strings in subsequent bash commands?

Tags: bash

I'm pretty unfamiliar with bash syntax and I'm running into a problem of how to use strings from a previous operation as inputs into subsequent ones. Here's what I have now:

```
#!/bin/bash

searchTerm=$1

results=$(npm search $searchTerm --json | jq '.[].name')

for term in $results
do
  info=$(npm info $term)

  echo "####" $info
done
```

The command that executes looks like the following and fails:

```
npm info "\"exampleTerm\""
```

How do I use `$term` in the for loop in combination with `npm info`?

Comment: Answer: info=$(eval npm info "$term")

Comment: What does the output of `npm search $searchTerm --json | jq '.[].name'` look like?

Answer (score 1):

A (long) one-liner will do it…

```
npm search react-redux --json | jq '.[].name' | xargs -I pkg sh -c 'echo "#### $(npm info $1)"' - pkg
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is to use eval like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

searchTerm=$1

results=$(npm search $searchTerm --json | jq '.[].name')

for term in $results
do
  info=$(eval npm info "$term")

  echo "####" $info
done
```